# Mandar en el cuerpo de un mail (vb.NET), el texto del mensaje y la firma html

Tags: vb.net, .net

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente problema.

Necesito enviar un mail a través de vb.net, todo funciona correctamente hasta que cargo :

> Archivo .html (Firma con imagenes embebidas)
>   Contenido del textBoxMensaje (Es donde el usuario escribe el mensaje del body del mail)

```
Public Sub mailSinAdjunto()
        Dim messageSinAdjunto As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
        If (txtPara.Text = "" Or txtAsunto.Text = "" Or txtPara.Text = "") Then
            MsgBox(mensajeTextosVacios)
        Else

            'Configuracion del STMP
            smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(Login, Password)
            smtp.Port = PuertoSMTP.ToString
            smtp.Host = ServidorSMTP.ToString

            ' Configuracion del mensaje
            messageSinAdjunto.[To].Add(txtPara.Text)
            messageSinAdjunto.From = New MailAddress(DireccionEmailEnvio, NombreMostrar, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            messageSinAdjunto.Subject = txtAsunto.Text.ToString
            messageSinAdjunto.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            messageSinAdjunto.Priority = MailPriority.High

            If rdbSSL.Checked = True Then
                smtp.EnableSsl = True
            Else
                smtp.EnableSsl = False
            End If

            If rdbTextoPlano.Checked = True Then

                messageSinAdjunto.IsBodyHtml = False
                messageSinAdjunto.Body = txtMensaje.Text

            ElseIf rdbTextoHtml.Checked = True Then

                Dim allMensajeMail As String
                messageSinAdjunto.IsBodyHtml = True
                allMensajeMail = txtMensaje.Text.ToString

                Dim htmlView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(textoHtml, Nothing, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)

                Dim imgCorreoBody As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource(logoCorreo, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
                imgCorreoBody.ContentId = "logoBody"
                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imgCorreoBody)

                Dim imgCorreoHeader As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource(logoCorreo, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
                imgCorreoHeader.ContentId = "logoHeader"
                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imgCorreoHeader)
                Dim textoMensaje As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(allMensajeMail, Nothing, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain)

                messageSinAdjunto.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)
                messageSinAdjunto.AlternateViews.Add(textoMensaje)

            End If
            Try
                smtp.Send(messageSinAdjunto)
                listErrores.Text = (mensajeEnviado)
            Catch ex As Exception
                listErrores.Text = (mensajeNoEnviado & ex.ToString)
                addLogArchivo(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Al usar :

> ```
> messageSinAdjunto.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)
> messageSinAdjunto.AlternateViews.Add(textoMensaje)
> ```

Si dejo los dos, solo me aparece la firma.html en el mail.
Si pongo primero el mensaje de texto, solo aparece el mensaje 
Si lo concateno, me aparece el html sin formar(aparece el código)

Que podría utilizar para mandar ambas cosas ?
Gracias !!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes concatenarlos **antes** de formar el mensaje, cambiando:

```
Dim htmlView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(textoHtml, Nothing, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
```

Por:

```
Dim htmlView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(textoHtml & allMensajeMail, Nothing, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
```

Después solo tienes que añadir `messageSinAdjunto.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)` en vez de los dos, ya que se concateno anteriormente, también puedes quitar `Dim textoMensaje As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(allMensajeMail, Nothing, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain)` puesto ha que ya no se utiliza.

Resultado:

```
Public Sub mailSinAdjunto()
    Dim messageSinAdjunto As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
    If (txtPara.Text = "" Or txtAsunto.Text = "" Or txtPara.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox(mensajeTextosVacios)
    Else

        'Configuracion del STMP
        smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(Login, Password)
        smtp.Port = PuertoSMTP.ToString
        smtp.Host = ServidorSMTP.ToString

        ' Configuracion del mensaje
        messageSinAdjunto.[To].Add(txtPara.Text)
        messageSinAdjunto.From = New MailAddress(DireccionEmailEnvio, NombreMostrar, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        messageSinAdjunto.Subject = txtAsunto.Text.ToString
        messageSinAdjunto.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        messageSinAdjunto.Priority = MailPriority.High

        If rdbSSL.Checked = True Then
            smtp.EnableSsl = True
        Else
            smtp.EnableSsl = False
        End If

        If rdbTextoPlano.Checked = True Then

            messageSinAdjunto.IsBodyHtml = False
            messageSinAdjunto.Body = txtMensaje.Text

        ElseIf rdbTextoHtml.Checked = True Then

            Dim allMensajeMail As String
            messageSinAdjunto.IsBodyHtml = True
            allMensajeMail = txtMensaje.Text.ToString

            Dim htmlView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(textoHtml & allMensajeMail, Nothing, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)

            Dim imgCorreoBody As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource(logoCorreo, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
            imgCorreoBody.ContentId = "logoBody"
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imgCorreoBody)

            Dim imgCorreoHeader As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource(logoCorreo, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
            imgCorreoHeader.ContentId = "logoHeader"
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imgCorreoHeader)
            'Dim textoMensaje As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(allMensajeMail, Nothing, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain)

            messageSinAdjunto.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)
            'messageSinAdjunto.AlternateViews.Add(textoMensaje)

        End If
        Try
            smtp.Send(messageSinAdjunto)
            listErrores.Text = (mensajeEnviado)
        Catch ex As Exception
            listErrores.Text = (mensajeNoEnviado & ex.ToString)
            addLogArchivo(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

El contenido de las dos variables debe tener el mismo formato, puedes leer la plantilla HTML:

```
StreamReader lector = new StreamReader(ruta);
    contenido = lector.ReadToEnd();
    lector.Close(); 

//Tratas el contenido, añades textos, etc...

txtBody += contenido + "otro contenido";

// Puedes facilitar si tienes un HTML completo externo preparado
// y sustituyes una marca concreta del mismo por el contenido que tu quieras
txtBody = txtBody.Replace("##COMENTARIO##", tuComentario.ToString());

MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(txtFrom.ToString(), txtTo.ToString(), txtAsunto.ToString(), txtBody.ToString());
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    /// Aquí la configuración de tu SMTP
    smtpClient.Credentials = ...
    smtp.Send(mm);
```

Recuerda que el resultado del cuerpo del email debe ser correcto HTML con sus etiquetas correspondientes.